# Searching string in a file and outputting the line number

Tags: file, shell, awk, grep

```
awk '$0 ~ str{print b}{b=$0}' str="findme" path_to_file
```

with this I can get the line before the found string's line.
How can I print its line number?

Comment: After seeing comment to thelux4, I can say it's unclear what you want. From the question it looks like you wanted to get line with str (instead of line before it), so as I answered already, you should just go with `print`, e.g. `awk -v str="findme" '$0 ~ str {print}' path_to_file`. But if you want the line number (question is wrong then), use `NR` built-in variable.

Comment: question is not wrong, "How can I print its line number?" states that i want the line number.

Comment: It sounded different originally: `with this i can get the line before the found string's line. How can i also print its line?` It was fixed by @Johan 6.5h after my comment was sent. After commenting under @eyadof answer you should realize that your question needs fixing, and my comment back then should convince you even more to better phrase it. Be always precise as much as you can and don't pretend you were when actually you weren't. It's easy to check (especially by yourself as the OP), so I don't know why are you bringing this up now.

Comment: I meant line number actually there but anyway maybe i should have been more clear. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NR` to get the current line (record) number:

```
awk '$0 ~ str{print NR-1 FS b}{b=$0}' str="findme" path_to_file
```

Comment: +1. You can just `print NR-1, b` instead of explicitly using `FS`

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret the question correctly, and you simply want to print the line number of the line that precedes any line containing a given string, you can do:

```
$ awk '/findme/{print NR - 1}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
awk '$0 ~ str{print b;print}{b=$0}' str="findme" path_to_file
```

Or, if you don't mind a slightly different output, in which there are '--' separating groups of found lines:

```
grep -B1 findme path_to_file
```

In this case, you search for the string "findme" within the file 'path_to_file'. The *-B1* flag says, "also prints 1 line before that."

Answer (score -1):

you can use `echo $(awk '$0 ~ str{print b}{b=$0}' str="findme" path_to_file)`

Comment: this prints the line. I want the number of line actually not the line itself.